# Trying to give groups the ability to have own URL in Grails. (Similar to how you could browse to facebook.com/{username})

Tags: grails, groovy, url-mapping

I am developing a group based web application in Grails (1.3.7) and one of the fields I have is groupUrl for my Group domain.  The theory behind it is I want to give users the ability to browse to http://www.myapp.com/{userDefinedgroupUrl}

I also want to be able to have www.myapp.com/{userDefinedGroupUrl}/$action?/$id? However, with the way I have it implemented now, I have to hardcode all of my other controllers in the mappings as well so they are matched first and executed properly.

Right now, I have it working with something like

```
mappings = { 
    "/group/$action?/$id?"(controller:"group")
    "/user/$action?/$id?"(controller: "user")
    etc..
    "/$groupUrl?/$action?/$id?"(controller: "group")
    "/$groupUrl?/events/$action?/id?"(controller: "groupEvents")
}
```

I think it actually is working right now (I didn't test it too thoroughly yet) but I was wondering if there is a better, more efficient way of accomplishing this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what you are doing is the right way to do it.

Comment: So after finally finding some time to play with this, I ended up keeping it the same way I originally posted and just hard coded all my controllers in the mappings. I didn't want to have the "/g" in the URL and tried using the wildcard mappings, but without success. I figure it won't be so bad now that all my controllers are in there and I'll just have to remember to add the entries when adding new controllers.  The main work (which was expected) was adjusting my actions/filters/views accordingly to force the URL structure.  Thank you all for your feedback!

Answer (score 4):

First, it might be better to put all your groups under a sub-path, which makes managing the controllers a lot easier, like this:

```
mappings = { 
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"()
    "/g/$groupUrl?/$action?/$id?"(controller: "group")
    "/g/$groupUrl?/events/$action?/id?"(controller: "groupEvents")
}
```

Second, Grails [URL Mappings](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4%20URL%20Mappings) allow for dynamic controllers and actions, so you could use a little code to select the correct controller, like so:

```
mappings = { 
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"()
    "/g/$groupUrl/$group_c?/$action?/$id?" {
        controller = {
            (params.group_c in [null, '', 'group']) ?
                'group' :
                'group' + params.group_c.capitalize()
        }

    }
}
```

That's not perfect, but basically it allows for the following URLs:

- /g/mygroup/ -> GroupController.index
- /g/mygroup/group/view/45 -> GroupController.view
- /g/mygroup/event/list/64 -> GroupEventController.list

It does not, however, allow for `GroupController` actions to be represented without the `/group/` path.  You could get around this by hard-coding a list of actions on the `GroupController`, and if `group_c` is in that list, bump `group_c` to `action` and bump `action` to `id`.  That would be kinda ugly.

Comment: Also, if you don't want the `/g/` with a slash, you might be able to embed a prefix, and use [Wildcard Mappings](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4.6%20Mapping%20Wildcards)

Comment: `'group' + params.group_c.capitalize()` is probably easier to read ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates Doh!  I searched but couldn't find one quickly.  Thanks - I'll update that right away.

Comment: Hopefully I will get to play around with this tonight.  I actually am trying to accomplish this without the /g/, so I will mess around with the wildcard mappings. Thanks, your help is much appreciated! I will also post the code when I have it all figured out.